# What does single character dot mean in google search?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was reading a book about GHDB and i faced this:

intitle:index.of

results:36,000

intitle:"index of"

results:18,000

so , what does dot character mean in search ?

Comment: Just what is your coding problem? Why not do some research on how Google Search works?

Comment: @Tedinoz , i did , but i dont understand it , because i dont have a good english language , can you help ?

Comment: Most non-alphanumeric characters are ignored unless designated as search operators. The dot/period character is not designated so it has no significance in [Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=e). Searching `index.of` in the title is the equivalent to searching `indexof`. In your book, the terms `index`, `indexof`, `index of`, and any/all other combinations may have significance in many scenarios. FWIW, I think you would have received a better response on [StackExchange Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

Most characters outside of the standard `a-z,A-z,0-9` are ignored by Google search. The single period, '.', is one of them. In Gmail search however, a single period acts as a wildcard catch-all term, so for example searching 'color.' would return mails with 'color' and, for example, mails with 'colorful' or 'colorless' in them too.

You can find more about Google Search Operators [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en), though this is not a typical question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company).